# How to show and bind base64 string to Image as a source in Nativescript?

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

I am trying to show and bind base64 image as ImageSource in my View, but it does not show up at all. I couldn't find any helpful information on this in documentation .. am I doing something wrong?

imageSource is property that should hold Image src data ..

Here is the View:

```
<Page loaded = "loaded" xmlns = "http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" >
    <StackLayout>
        <TextField hint = "String for encoding!" text = "{{ message }}" />
        <Button  tap = "{{ onGenerateQrTap }}" text = "Generate QR" class = "button" />
        <Image src = "{{ imageSource }} " />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

here is the code behind View:

```
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
import { QrGeneratorViewModel } from '../../ViewModels/QrGeneratorViewModel';
import { Button } from 'ui/button';
import { Image } from 'ui/image';

let viewModel =  new QrGeneratorViewModel();

export function loaded(args: EventData) {
  let page = <Page>args.object;
  page.bindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

and here is the ViewModel:

```
import { Observable } from 'data/observable';
import { QrGenerator } from '../Common/QrGenerator';
import { ImageSource } from "image-source";

export class QrGeneratorViewModel extends Observable {

    private _message: string;
    private _qrGenerator: QrGenerator.Generator;
    private _imageBase64String: string;
    private _imageSource: ImageSource;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._qrGenerator = new QrGenerator.Generator();
        this._imageSource = new ImageSource();
    }

    get message() {
        return this._message;
    }

    set message(newMessage: string) {
        this._message = newMessage;
    }

    get imageSource(): ImageSource {
        return this._imageSource;
    }

    public onGenerateQrTap(): void {
        this._imageBase64String = this._qrGenerator.qr(this._message);
        this._imageSource.loadFromBase64(this._imageBase64String);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quickly skimming the code it doesn't look like you are setting the `_imageSource` for it to update. You call the method on the `ImageSource` instance but nothing to set the UI binding. I would try having a setter for the `_imageSource` or setting it with the Observable:

`this.set('imageSource', this._imageSource.loadFromBase64(this._imageBase64String);`