# Nativescript : Display an image using a Base64 string

Tags: android, angular, image, base64, nativescript

I'm Here today because I've a problem to **decode Base64 string with nativescript angular.**

So, in my situation, **I've a listview of Image**, like this :

```
<GridLayout class="page page-content">
        <ListView [items]="Dogs" class="List">
            <ng-template let-item="item">
               <StackLayout class="Container"> 
                <Image class="Logo" src="{{item.img}}"></Image>                 
               </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView> 
   </GridLayout>
```

There is nothings special, it just a list to show my images.

Then in my typescript, I've a array like this :

```
Dogs = [{img: fromBase64('FirstBase64String')},{img: fromBase64('SecondBase64String')},{img= fromBase64('ThirdBase64String')}];
```

**But it does'nt display the image** and i don't have any error message.
 I've also try the classic javascript method, but she does'nt work.

So here my questions :

**How can I display my images using my Base64String ?**

Keep in mind that I've to use a Listview, I know **Listview** can be problematic.
  But **I've no choice but to use it.**
  Also, ***I'm on Android***, I don't know if it matter.

Thank you.

Comment: You may need to use `_sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812993/base64-to-image-angular-2/43661231)

Comment: Thanks, but it does'nt work

Comment: Where does `fromBase64` method come from in your code? Can you the complete sample code?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=GSWP47&v=3) for you. In my html I have a list view like this.

```
<ListView class="list-group" [items]="countries" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)"
        style="height:1250px">
        <ng-template let-country="item">
            <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
                <Image [src]="country.img" class="thumb img-circle"></Image>
                <Label [text]="country.name" class="list-group-item-heading"
                    verticalAlignment="center" style="width: 60%"></Label>
            </FlexboxLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
```

and in my typescript, I am passing mix of encoded64string and image path and {NS} imagesource handles it automatically. Still if you want to play with [fromBase64](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource#fromBase64) & [loadFromBase64](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource#loadfrombase64) you can refere this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328606/how-to-show-and-bind-base64-string-to-image-as-a-source-in-nativescript/40331258#40331258).

P.S. `fromBase64` returns a Promise while `loadFromBase64` returns a boolean.

Comment: Thanks, but I've the Bad Base 64 error, despite having a valid Base64